# How to draw a calendar, populated with Google Calendar Events?

Tags: angularjs, calendar

I googled all over but couldn't find any component that will draw and populated calendar with google calendar events using AngularJS.

I found ui-calendar (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) which is based on fullCalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/)

but it is not working, doesnt populate calendar with events.

I opened https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.5.1/demos/basic-views.html

looked in the source code and did exactly the same, created an array of events, exactly as in this example, and nothing is displayed in the calendar.

Is there any other component that actually works ???

Answer (score 0):

Do you try for something like this, [ https://demo.vaadin.com/calendar ]
Also Vaadin gives you the same Calendar as Googleand you should be able to use it with AngularJS. I hope it's what you need.

Best Regards..

Comment: But I dont see any documentation, any AngularJS code examples, nothing. Who or what is that vaadin ?? Where is Google Calendar events retrieval code, that binds the results to that calendar ?

Comment: here is the link [ https://vaadin.com ], I'm a  java programmer and using Vaadin in my Projects, Vaadin is a web Component that you can use, but as I read in the Forum, Vaadin is compatible with Angularjs and Vaadin calendar is now OpenSource and free to use. make a search in Vaadin.com there's a lot of post about Vaadin and angularjs. If it helps, please tell me too.

Comment: and btw, they have a great support team, thats a good point about them.